# use ubuntu rsa key in windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rsa, gitlab, git-bash

I've generated `ssh_rsa` & `ssh_rsa.pub` on my ubuntu workstation so I could access gitlab using ssh.
It works, now I want my PC to also use these keys.
So I copied the generated `id_rsa` from my ubuntu workstation and pasted it to `/C/users/myUserName/.ssh/` via git-bash.

But my pc still can't connect to gitlab repo, it prints:

```
$ ssh -v git@gitlab.company.com -P 22  
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015  
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/config   
debug1: /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for gitlab.company.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.company.com [192.xxx.xxx.x] port 22.  
debug1: Connection established.  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1  
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0  
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1  
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, ssh will look for `.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`, *not* `ssh_rsa`.

So first, try and rename those keys (private and public) to their default name.

And make sure the public key (copied in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`) has been copied as *one* line.

Note: You need to copy both the private *and* the public key.

Or at least, generate the public key for the private key `id_rsa` you have copied.

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\.ssh
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa  > id_rsa.pub
```

Make sure to add Git path to your `%PATH%`:

```
> where ssh-keygen
D:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\ssh-keygen.exe
```